# Double query with proper count

Tags: php, mysql

I'm afraid i have written a query & confused myself in the process despite it being quite simple.

I have 2 mysql tables.

```
Table1 has ... orderID, productID, quantity
Table2 has ... orderID, status, time
```

I need to do a query that will do the following...

```
Output (1 per line) 
productID - Quantity  where status = 1 & time < $lastactive.
```

I tried doing a query of Table 2 to fetch productID and count Quantity but then if 2 different orderID's have the same productID then it doesnt total them. Any help greatly appreciated (name of tables/rows are accurante).

Example:

```
orderID 123, productID 2, quantity 4
orderID 123, productID 5, quantity 6
orderID 678, productID 2, quantity 5
```

would output:

```
2   9
5   6
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use something similar to this:

```
select t1.productId, Sum(t1.quantity) Total
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
  on t1.orderid = t2.orderid
where t2.status = 1
  and t2.time < $lastactive
group by t1.productid
```

Comment: I hadn't i always got confused when using inner join and sum at the same time so avoided it. 

Im using mysql_fetch_array so would the output be.. $row->t1.productID $row->sum[t1.quantity]; 

This is why i get so confused lol

Comment: @MichaelClarke Unless you want to become a DBA, better use a query builder tool.